# Why is CSS hover not applying to HTML buttons?

Tags: html, css, colors, hover

I have those buttons and I tried to make them to change color on hover.

```css
.social:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #28ad00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:2.6s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-spotify"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:3.0s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:3.4s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:3.8s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:4.2s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:4.6s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The result is them not changing the color on hover, so any type of help is greatly appreciated. I'm new here, sorry for any mistakes.

Full code is on https://codepen.io/stressardo/pen/OJOoMoy, I assume it's too long to post it there directly.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. The code you provided in the question is not sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It seems ok to me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue either. The code works just fine for me as intended. As such voting to clsoe as not reproducible.

Comment: The issue is on codepen, the code is working here in SO

Comment: @SigurdMazanti if an issue can not be reproduced on SO then it has no value for SO. If an issue can only be reprodcued on external resources then the question itself is not self-containing. As such it msises the core guidelines of SO. I not going to check every external resources to find an issue a user might have. If he can't provide the necessary details and informations ehre, then the guidelines are evry strict and clear: closure for `not reproducible or caused by typos` or `missing debugging details`

Comment: I looked at your pen, it works if I target the actual i class containing the image like this .fa-spotify:hover {color:#000;} - obviously the color is not the one you want but this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the hover effect to the `<i>`
element instead.

Edit: I forgot to specify this solution works in your codepen example.

```css
.social i:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#28ad00;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:2.6s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-spotify"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:3.0s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:3.4s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:3.8s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:4.2s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></td>
    <td class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay:4.6s;"><a href="" target="_blank" class="social"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: invalid targeting. You cant hover the icon as the pointer-event of the anchor will prevent it. If youw ant to do this you have to use `a:hover i`

Comment: @tacoshy it works, though.

Comment: @stress auto-correction of browsers. It might work but there is no garuntee it will work for every browser or that the auto-correction will keep correcting those programming erros in future. Just ebcause invalid markups or targeting work in some cases it should not be adviced to sue them.

Comment: @tacoshy The empty a tag is the parent element and the child is the image. The a tag becomes clickable because of the width and height content of the child image so CSS hover effects tied to the child will obviously work. So far I haven't encountered any issues on any popular modern browser using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "i" tag to it. See below.

```
.social i:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #28ad00;
    }
```